# Replace WooCommerce cart shipping section with a custom text message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I already cleared billing fields on checkout page, but unfortunately they are still remembered on cart page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'reigel_empty_checkout_billing_fields', 10, 2 );

function reigel_empty_checkout_billing_fields( $value, $input ) {

    if ( in_array( $input, $billing_fields ) ) {
        $value = '';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

I just want to display on cart page an information, that the shipping costs will show in the next step after filling shipping fields. Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will remove the shipping section on cart, replacing it by a custom message:

```
// Remove "shipping" section from cart page only
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_cart_needs_shipping' );
function filter_cart_needs_shipping( $needs_shipping ) {
    return is_cart() ? false : $needs_shipping;
}

// Add a custom shipping message row
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'cart_custom_shipping_message_row' );
function cart_custom_shipping_message_row() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) :

    $shipping_message = __("Costs will be calculated on next step.", "woocommerce");
    ?>
    <tr class="shipping">
        <th><?php _e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td class="message" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><em><?php echo $shipping_message; ?></em></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]